# Stop video when kendo window is closed

Tags: jquery, .net, sharepoint, kendo-window

I am in a requirement wherein i am supposed to load a .aspx page in kendo modal popup. Loaded page can open a video. But when i close the window the video is still played in background.

Can anyone suggest me solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $(dialog).find('iframe').remove() or kendo.destroy(dialog) which should halt the continued execution of that page. If you have to resort to destroy (which with things like video playback and flash you might need to), then make sure to re-initialize your dialog object so you can use it again if needbe.